# animate background color of an item (Display block)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve an effect like on that website www.momkai.com
When I hover an item (a li set to display as a block) I want the background color to animate from left to right. Any ideas how to achieve it? Ideally without images.

Comment: Momkai uses JavaScript (mootools) to do the animation, you could do something similar using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The way they do it is by showing the first image (white - black text) then on mouseover animate the clip (http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_clip.asp) style of a second image (black - white text) which is on top of the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using CSS3 transitions. They are pretty well supported: http://caniuse.com/#search=transition

An example:
http://jsfiddle.net/VirusZ/6VnTm/

Comment: "Windows Internet Explorer 7 and later, in standards-compliant mode (strict !DOCTYPE), can apply the :hover pseudo-class to any element, not only links." [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530766.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530766.aspx) While IE does not have any css3 transitions, the effect will be there, just without the animation.

Comment: Used your technique since my website is HTML5 - CSS3 anyways. worked wonders, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to use a background image and animate the background position with something like jQuery, but for a no-images option use something like this:

```
<div>
  <span>link text</span>
  <div class="bgcolor"></div>
</div>

div {
  position: relative;
  background: #F00;
  width: 200px;
}

div div.bgcolor {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  background: #FF0;
}
```

and on document load

```
li.hover(function() {
  $(this).children(".bgcolor").animate({width:"200px"});
}, function() {
  $(this).children(".bgcolor").animate({width:"0px"});
});
```