# How to add slide animate on Bootstrap Navbar hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add smooth slide hover effect on Bootstrap navbar at this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/T62Ep/2/). What I would like to do is sliding the active class style horizontally on each hovered nav.

As you can see from my try right now styles just jumps on the top of any hovered element and the Active class still stay there.

Here is the CSS I am using for this:

```
.navbar-nav>li {
    width: 120px;
    text-align:center
}
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.navbar .nav > .active > a, .navbar .nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar .nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: darkgreen;
    color: white;
}
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
    background-color: darkgreen;
    color: white;
}
```

I also used this jQuery which didn't go through:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $(".navbar .nav > li > a").on("mouseenter", function() {
       $( '.navbar .nav > li' ).addClass( "active" );
       
   }).on("mouseleave", function() {
    $( '.navbar .nav > li' ).removeClass( "active" );
}); 
});
```

How can I make the navbar more interactive by adding hover/slide effect?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486094/animate-background-color-of-an-item-display-block

Comment: Hi Bass but this is not the answer for my question as I want to move background style from one li to hovered on